# Wireless roaming is messing up resolv.conf

Tags: wpa-supplicant, dhclient

Here's my wifi `interfaces`

```
#auto wlp1s0
allow-hotplug wlp1s0
iface wlp1s0 inet manual
        wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
#        up /usr/sbin/wondershaper -a wlan0 -d 9500 -u 15000
#        down /usr/sbin/wondershaper -a wlan0 -c

allow-hotplug RWB
iface RWB inet dhcp
```

where `RWB` is an AP defined in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Whenever I connected to that AP the `dhclient` (I presume) updates the file `/etc/resolv.conf`.
This means that when I go away from `RWB` and connect to something else -- including wired ethernet -- DNS fails because the IP address in `resolv.conf` is nolonger routable.

Naive fix is to stop `dhcp` client from updating `resolv.conf`, but surely there is a conventional configuration for this situation that solves this problem -- what?

Comment: You can try setting `immutable` flag to file /etc/resolv.conf `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` to prevent resolv.conf from being overwritten. This is some way to solve this problem but it isn't a good way

Comment: It might be being managed by systemd-resolved.service, though resolv.conf would probably say if it was. What OS is it?

Answer (score 0):

can not comment yet so offering this as an answer.  this youtube walks through setting permanent DNS nameservers on Ubuntu/Debian with resolv.conf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NEyXDdBrw2c

like @Hack Saw commented systemd may manage resolve.conf , that can cause problems permanently changing dns nameservers in resolve.conf

Answer (score 0):

From the `man` page of `dhclient` -

```
BUGS
       If more than one interface is being used, there's no obvious way to avoid
clashes between server-supplied configuration parameters - for example, the stock
dhclient-script rewrites /etc/resolv.conf ...
```

`dhclient` uses a shell script to configure the system when DHCP events occur. To prevent `dhclient` from overwriting `resolv.conf`, you'll need to modify the default behavior of this script. But first, you'll need to install and run something like `systemd-resolved` that can manage the DNS information for multiple network interfaces.

Here's an example of how one would modify `dhclient` to update DNS information using `systemd-resolved` instead of overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf` -

`/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/dns-update`

```
#!/bin/sh

make_resolv_conf(){
    # DHCPv4
    if [ -x /usr/bin/systemd-resolve ]; then
        if [ -n "$new_domain_name" ]; then
            systemd-resolve --interface="$interface" --set-domain="${new_domain_name%% *}"
        fi
        if [ -n "$new_domain_name_servers" ]; then
            for nameserver in $new_domain_name_servers; do
                systemd-resolve --interface="$interface" --set-dns="$nameserver"
            done
        fi
    fi
}
```

This script is called before `dhclient` applies system configuration received from DHCP, and overwrites the stock `make_resolv_conf()`.

Depending on your OS, there might not be a `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d` dir. In that case, you'd place the script in an executable file called `/etc/dhclient-enter-hooks`.